# CSS make background-image overlay other div

Tags: css, background-image

[image]

Basically I want the background-image (the logo) to overlay the white div below it, I tried my best using z-indexes etc and Googling but I can't manage to get it fixed.

I know the question is a duplicate but Im desperate since other solutions didnt work out for me. 
Most likely it's an easy fix, I posted the website online here: http://tostimc.net/stackoverflow/ so you guys can see my code etc.

Comment: Css problems should include the code in a reproducible manner (ideally in a form of a runable fiddle). As you've said, it's not an unique problem, so if existing solutions don't work for you, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I uploaded it to my web-server so the code is viewable, I hope that works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding   `z-index: -1;` to you `.panel-default` class in the css file: tosti.css rule 215

Comment: Thanks alot for the fix, that is indeed what I was trying to do and it works perfectly!

Comment: Accepted this one as the answer, thanks for your help!